# Google Analytics: Identical Views for Same Property Displaying Different Real-Time Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I copied a View to begin incrementally altering it, while testing in real-time, to develop a simple conversion-funnel tracking effort. Both views have been set up with same host name and neither have any filters applied.

When I navigate to our site, my user shows up in real time on only ONE of these views. We have other users displaying in real-time across both views, but again I'm only showing up on one. again, No IP filtering applied.

I can't put my finger on why I'm being excluded from one view but not the other when both views' configurations are EXACTLY identical. Any insights?

Edit: The only settings configured for both are the "View Settings" Both with the exact same "Website's URL" set to www.hostname.com/ , both using https. No other settings configured. No filters, nothing..

Moreover - I have now created third, exact copy of my "All Web Site Data" View and each view shows different Real-Time data. This makes me sad.

Comment: Please, share some of your configurations or code. Are you getting some kind of error? DevConsole shows nothing unusual?

Comment: @statosdotcom Code will not change a view (code is relevant to data collection, which happens on property level). Incidentally this means the question is most likely off-topic.

Comment: Hi, were u able to figure out the solution. I am having identical issue.